# spring cloud contract verifier test fails with spring cloud bus

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-contract, spring-cloud-bus

I use spring-cloud-contract to test rabbitmq messages between 2 applications. A simple application is created here. https://github.com/winster/contract-test-sample  (lombok free)

But if I add `spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp` to the producer dependencies (with or without replacing `spring-boot-starter-amqp`), the auto-generated `ContractVerifierTest` on producer side fails with following trace.

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

```
2020-11-09 17:06:15.326 ERROR 3872 --- [           main] m.s.StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver : Exception occurred while trying to read a message from  a channel with na
me [custom-event-exchange]

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'custom-event-exchange' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.
10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1115) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver.receive(StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver.java:47) [spring-cl
oud-contract-verifier-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver.receive(StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver.java:61) [spring-cl
oud-contract-verifier-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver.receive(StreamPollableChannelMessageReceiver.java:29) [spring-cl
oud-contract-verifier-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:59) [spring-cloud-contract-verifier-2.2.4.RELEASE.
jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:30) [spring-cloud-contract-verifier-2.2.4.RELEASE.
jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging.receive(ContractVerifierMessaging.java:44) [spring-cloud-contract-verifie
r-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.example.producer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_custom_event(ContractVerifierTest.java:30) [test-classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686) [junit-platform-commons-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.
6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:
5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:
5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-plat
form-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-plat
form-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platfor
m-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.393 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.producer.ContractVerifierTest
[ERROR] validate_custom_event  Time elapsed: 4.417 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'custom-event-exchange' available
        at com.example.producer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_custom_event(ContractVerifierTest.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'custom-event-exchange' available
        at com.example.producer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_custom_event(ContractVerifierTest.java:30)

2020-11-09 17:06:20.669  INFO 3872 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that verifier was using `stream` implementation instead of `amqp`. Inside `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging`, there are different implementations of `MessageVerifier`is available. Somehow without explicitly enabling `stream` was used. Hence the solution for above problem is to add following in `test/resources/application.properties`

```
stubrunner.stream.enabled=false
```

along with `stubrunner.amqp.enabled=true`